# Pulling and force commit set of changes

Tags: version-control, merge, mercurial, tortoisehg

I have the follow situation:

Repository A:
    1a -> 2a -> 3a -> 4a -> 5a

Repository B:
    1b -> 2b-> 3b -> 4b

In repo B, the first commit is a snapshot of the Revision 3a of repo A PLUS some changes.

I Would really like to merge repo B in A, preserving the history and relationship, because even if they are two separate repositories, in reality they are related. because B started from repo A at revision 3a
What i need is to pull the changeset from B to A in a branch:

1a -> 2a -> 3a -> 4a -> 5a

```
         |
         |

         1b -> 2b -> 3b -> 4b
```

I could safety overwrite all the content in the branch at 3a' because 1b is a modification of 3a'.
But when i pull with force parameter it keeps pulling as a non unrelated changeset, creating a new origin.
How can i tell to mercurial that i want to pull the changeset from B as if i would be committing them? so i can keep the relationship.

I tried patch queue, but it reject all the content when i try to apply them.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Patch queue is how I would approach it. If `3a` and `3a'` are really the same state, I would expect a patch queue to work. Note that you need to update to `3a` and then apply `1b`, etc.

Comment: @Edward Sorry i updated my question deleting 3a', because the frist commit of B is 1b wich is 3a plus some changes, i´ll try again patch queue. perhaps i have to commit by hand 1b in a new branch updated to 3a and then i can patch queue the rest of the changes (2b, 3b, 4b)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the reason the patches aren't working as expected is because there is a difference between changeset `3a` and `1b`. After understanding (I hope!) your update, here's how I would proceed.

1. Update to `3a` in the main repository
2. File copy the state of 1b over top of it and commit it (as `3a1`?)
3. Export the changes in the second repo as a series of patches.
4. Import the series of patches one at a time onto the ne branch.
5. Merge the changes into tip.

(I think this is close to what you mentioned in you comment about "committing `b1` by hand", but thought I would expand on it a bit.)